# Настольное приложение, используя React и C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, react-native, desktop

С помощью каких технологий и каким образом создать настольное приложение, используя `React` для создания графического интерфейса, а в качестве логики приложения `C#`.
В частности, будет просто прекрасно, если существует какой-то способ использовать библиотеки `.NET` из `React Native`.

Comment: Не очень понятно, как вы себе это представляете... а главное - зачем? И на сколько ваше будущее приложение настольное?

Comment: Веб в десктоп сейчас суют все, я думаю труда не составит найти нужное (например, Electron). Даже самый современный у .NET - MAUI пошел в это направление и позволяет запускать Blazor сайты как десктоп приложение (Blazor Hybrid).